# Libreoffice for openjdk docker container

Tags: java, linux, docker, libreoffice

I have openjdk:8-alpine image, I have installed libreoffce with sh and `apk add LibreOffice` command and I try to run `soffice --headless` command, but I get:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

I've checked java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.12.0) (Alpine 8.212.04-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile to reproduce above issue ?

Comment: @fly2matrix I use docker-compose like this: my-container:
    image: openjdk:8-alpine
    working_dir: /opt/app
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
    volumes:
      - ./my-container/:/opt/app:ro
    command: java -jar -Xmx256m my-jar.jar
    ports:
      - 8080:8080